# Segmentation fault при разыменовании struct sockaddr_in*

Tags: c++, linux, сокет, указатели, segmentation-fault

Имеется следующий код:

```
struct sockaddr_in m_destAddr;
std::string ipAddrString = "127.0.0.1"
struct addrinfo hints, *res;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_RAW;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_ICMP;
if (getaddrinfo(ipAddrString.c_str(), NULL, &hints, &res) != 0)
{
    m_errorText = "Failed to resolve IP address";
    m_errorCode = 4;
    return;
}
m_destAddr = *(struct sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr;
```

На последней строке происходит ошибка сегментации. Немного поисследовав, пришел к выводу, что это происходит при попытке разыменования `res->ai_addr`. Я проверил, `res` и `res->ai_addr` не являются `nullptr`.

Я написал следующий уточняющий код:

```
struct sockaddr* address = res->ai_addr;
struct sockaddr_in* ipv4Address = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(address);
auto a = *ipv4Address;
```

Падение однозначно происходит при разыменовании `*ipv4Address`.

Почему это происходит и как сделать правильно?

Comment: Вопрос, а зачем вам это нужно? Похоже на проблему XY.

Comment: На [странице справки](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) написано, что последний параметр функции `getaddrinfo` - указатель на связанный список одной или нескольких структур addrinfo , содержащих сведения об ответе об узле. Из описания неясно, должно ли это значение быть чем-то изначально инициализировано, однако в примере на той же странице значение `res` изначально инициализировано `NULL`. Попробуйте и вы написать `struct addrinfo hints, *res = NULL;`.

Comment: @maestro, туда передается указатель на указатель, чтобы записать адрес ответа. Так что не нужно туда ничего записывать.

Comment: Вероятно, поведение функции зависит от того, чем инициализирован последний параметр `&res`. Если это `NULL`, то функция создаёт новый связный список и записывает его по переданному указателю (по адресу `&res`). Если это не `NULL`, то функция работает с переданным указателем `res` как с существующим связным списком. В вашем случае переменная `res` не инициализирована, то есть в ней содержится мусор, а мусор - это не `NULL`. В итоге программа пытается обратиться по "мусорному" адресу и падает.

Comment: @evo, тем не менее, это единственное значимое отличие, которое я нашёл. Код возврата автор проверяет, и при ошибке в работе функции `getaddrinfo` проблемная строка не выполняется.

Comment: @maestro Я добавил зануление переменной ```res```, это не помогло.

Comment: А зачем здесь разыменовывание: `m_destAddr = *(struct sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr;`? Смотрите пример по ссылке: `sockaddr_ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) ptr->ai_addr;`

Comment: @maestro Вы ссылаетесь на документацию Windows, я же пишу для Linux.

Comment: @maestro разыменование нужно для того, чтобы вытащить структуру ai_addr.

Comment: Определения структуры `strict addrinfo` в [документации Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-addrinfoa) [и документации Linux](https://cs-education.github.io/sysassets/man_pages/html/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) абсолютно одинаковые.

Comment: То есть вы хотите применить операцию разыменовывания ко всему выражению `(struct sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr`? Добавьте скобочки: `*((struct sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr)`.

Comment: @maestro Дополнительные скобки не помогли: ```auto a = *((struct sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr);``` все равно вызывает сегфолт.

Comment: А зачем приведение к `struct sockaddr_in*`? Переменная `res` имеет тип `struct addrinfo*`, и он, похоже, не совместим с типом `struct sockaddr_in`.

Comment: @maestro ```struct addrinfo``` имеет своим членом ```struct sockaddr *ai_addr;```, который, насколько я понимаю, можно привести к ```struct sockaddr_in *``` Он мне и нужен.

Comment: @SergeyU, вы так и не объяснили зачем вам это нужно... Если не выходит разименовать, скопируйте!

Comment: @evo Приведенный код - часть конструктора. По результату его работы в переменную класса ```m_destAddr``` должен быть созранен адрес, с которым после будут работать другие методы. Я пробовал использовать ```memcpy```, это тоже приводит к сегфолту.

Comment: https://ideone.com/rIIxgr не воспроизводится.

Comment: Приведение вида `reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(address)` с последующем разыменованием можно выполнять только когда вы точно знаете (читайте: можете указать на место в документации, где это описано), что указатель реально указывает на экземпляр соотв. класса. А так непонятно, с чего вы решили так лихо что-то кастовать и удивляетесь результату. Даже `ai_addrlen` не проверили.

Comment: Каким компилятором вы пользуетесь? Я проверил g++ 11.4 и clang 10.0 -- ваш код работает без проблем: https://cplayground.com/?p=ram-gorilla-monkey